# Partial substitution fonts in equation

Tags: fonts

I can get decent opentype font use for text using XeLaTeX with the fontspec package, but very inconsistent font usage in equation mode. Can anyone offer suggestions?

```
\documentclass[10pt, bindingoffset=0.5in]{article}

\usepackage[inner=1.125in, outer=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}  

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[etex]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{index}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.55}
\definecolor{darkolivegreen}{rgb}{0.33, 0.42, 0.18}

\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Skolar PE}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{DTL Caspari TOT Medium}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}
$D_{\theta} \cos(\theta)=\lim_{\Delta\theta \to 0} [\cos(\theta+\Delta\theta)-cos(\theta)] \div \Delta\theta,$

$\int \sin(x) \, dx=-\cos(x)+c. \quad 3 \times 4 + 5 \le 17 \pm 2$
\end{document}
```

XeLaTeX vs InDesign:

[image: XeLaTeX vs InDesign]

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to load `unicode-math` instead of `fontspec`.  This will load Latin Modern Math, or any OpenType math font of your choice.  You can even set the mathematical alphanumeric symbols to use your text font.  Giving the package the command

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
```

will scale all the fonts for you automatically.

In XeLaTeX, you also have the option to load `mathspec` or `mathastext` to use the current text font for variables in math mode.

Finally, you can load a legacy math font package that matches your main font acceptably.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both mathspec (which loads fontspec) and mathastext with partial success. The letters will change to the correct opentype font, but numbers are in a different font and most of the math symbols (like /div /times and /abs) are in the wrong font. I was not able to use unicode-math successfully to solve this problem either. If a document is not math intensive, mathspec and mathastext work ok, but for a calculus textbook, they would not work. The legacy math font packages work well, but that gives up a lot of better designed fonts.

Comment: @Philo `unicode-math` should work fine if you set up the fonts you want. The other options should be used in conjunction with a legacy math font matching the text font.

Comment: @Philo I would post an example, but you seem to be using commercial fonts I don’t own.

Comment: Since your font looks Palatino-ish, perhaps  the following `unicode-math` set-up would work for you: `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}` followed by `\setmathfont{Asana Math}`, then `\setmathfont{Skolar PE Italic}[range=it]` and `\setmathfont{Skokar PE}[range=up]` would work for you. Tweak as needed.

Comment: I tried the \usepackage{unicode-math} instead of \usepackage{fontspec} or \usepackage{mathspec}, but the lines \setmathfont{AsanaMath} and \setmathfont{Skolar PE Italic}[range=it] both gave errors under XeLaTeX. It is probably my inexperience and I am missing something.

Comment: I added \usepackage{sansmath} and the \setmathfont{AsanaMath} works but the \setmathfont{Skolar PE Italic}[range=it] and \setmathfont{Skolar PE}[range=up] both gave errors.

Comment: @Philo Oh. Make sure you're up-to-date, and change them to \setmathfont[range=up]{Skolar PE}`. I might have left a typo in there.

Comment: hmmm. AsanaMath did not work, so I changed it to latinmodern. The part below works only until I remove the percent signs:

\usepackage{mathfont}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

%\setmathfont{SkolarPE-Italic.otf}[range=it]

%\setmathfont{SkolarPE-Rg.otf}[range=up]

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Skolar PE}

\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{DTL Caspari TOT Medium}

\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

Comment: I downloaded Asana-Math.otf and put it in the correct directory and changed your directions to \setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf} and it looks better. However, the other instructions for Skolar PE did not work, even with copying the font to the correct TEX directory.

Comment: @Philo Try changing to `\setmathfont[range=it]{SkolarPE-Italic.otf}`

Comment: No luck. The error I get with the change above is: Package fontspec Error: The font "SkolarPE-Italic" cannot be found. That font is both installed on the OS X font directory as well as the opentype TEX directory.

Comment: @Philo Add it to your system font book.

Comment: @Philo You could also use the `Path=` font option, from the `fontspec` manual.